# How to make Flask app debug mode to True in a Docker container

Tags: docker, flask

I'm running a Flask app in a Docker container but I'm having issues in debugging. In my container I have three micro-services.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  files:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
     [..]

  grafana:
     [..]

  prometheus:
     [..]

  aggregatore:
   [..] 

  classificatore:
    build: classificatore/.
    volumes:    
      - [..]
    volumes_from: 
      - files
    ports: 
      - [..]
    command: ["python", "/src/main.py"]
    depends_on: 
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy

  testmicro:
    [..]    
  rabbit:
    [..]
```

In the `classificatore` service, I build up the Docker as follows:

**classificatore/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
RUN mkdir /src
ADD requirements.txt /src/.
WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /src/.
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/reqdoc
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

In `classificatore/main.py` file

```
from time import time
from sam import firstRead, secondRead, lastRead, createClassificationMatrix
from sam import splitClassificationMatrix, checkIfNeedSplit, printMatrix
from util import Rabbit, log, moveFile
from uuid import uuid4
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, send_from_directory
import os
import configparser
import json
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Summary, Counter

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
rabbit = Rabbit()

inputDir = os.environ['INPUT_DIR'] if 'INPUT_DIR' in os.environ else config['DEFAULT']['INPUT_DIR']

# Create a metric to track time spent
REQUEST_TIME = Summary('classification_processing_seconds', 'Time spent to process a SAM file')
COUNTER_INPUT_FILE_SIZE = Counter('input_sam_size', 'Sum of input SAM file size')
COUNTER_OUTPUT_FILE_SIZE = Counter('output_sam_size', 'Sum of output SAM file size')
start_http_server(8000)

@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def classification(baseNameFile, AU_SIZE):
    nameFile = inputDir + "/" + baseNameFile
    startTime = time()

    numeroLetture = 1
    file_id = str(uuid4())
    log.info("Analizzo il file YYYYY (NomeFile: %s, Id: %s, AU_SIZE: %s)" % (nameFile, file_id, AU_SIZE))
    rnameArray, parameter_set = firstRead(nameFile)
    classificationMatrix = createClassificationMatrix(rnameArray)
    log.info("Creo un numero di range che dovrebbe dividire il file in file da %s reads" % (AU_SIZE))
    while (checkIfNeedSplit(classificationMatrix, AU_SIZE)):
        classificationMatrix = splitClassificationMatrix(classificationMatrix, AU_SIZE)
        log.info("Leggo il file di nuovo, perche' alcuni range sono troppo grandi")
        classificationMatrix = secondRead(nameFile, classificationMatrix)
        numeroLetture = numeroLetture + 1
    printMatrix(classificationMatrix)
    log.info("Sono state fatte %s letture" % (numeroLetture))
    log.info("Adesso scrivo i file")
    au_list = lastRead(nameFile, file_id, classificationMatrix, parameter_set['myRnameDict'])
    COUNTER_INPUT_FILE_SIZE.inc(os.path.getsize(nameFile))
    COUNTER_OUTPUT_FILE_SIZE.inc(moveFile(au_list, file_id))
    rabbit.enque_tasks(parameter_set, au_list, file_id)

    log.info("Tempo totale impiegato: %s sec" % int(time() - startTime))

app = Flask( __name__ , template_folder='./web')

@app.route("/")
def index(message=None):
    log.info("Sono PRin index!!!")
    samFiles = os.listdir(config['DEFAULT']['INPUT_DIR'])
    samFiles = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.sam'), samFiles))
    samFiles.sort()
    mpeggFiles = os.listdir(config['DEFAULT']['MPEGG_DIR'])
    mpeggFiles.sort()
    mpeggFiles = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.mpegg'), mpeggFiles))
    return render_template('index.html', samFiles=samFiles, mpeggFiles=mpeggFiles, message=message)

@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    f = request.files['file']
    f.save(os.path.join(config['DEFAULT']['INPUT_DIR'], f.filename))
    return index("Upload avvenuto con successo")

@app.route("/encode", methods=['POST'])
def encode():
    filename = request.form['filename']
    AU_SIZE = int(request.form['AU_SIZE'])
    classification(filename, AU_SIZE)
    return index("Encoding iniziato correttamente per il file: %s" % (filename))

@app.route('/download/<filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):
    log.info ("Download %s" % filename)
    mpeggDir = config['DEFAULT']['MPEGG_DIR']
    log.debug ("mpeggDir: %s" % mpeggDir)
    filepath = os.path.join(mpeggDir, filename)
    log.debug ("My filepath: %s" % filepath)
    return send_from_directory(directory=mpeggDir, filename=filename)



if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run( host = '0.0.0.0' , debug = False )
```

I build-up the app by running:

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up -d
```

To check logs in classificatore:

```
docker logs <mycontainername>
```

If in classificatore/main.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run( host = '0.0.0.0' , debug = False )
```

I get

```
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
2019-05-03 08:38:25,406  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

If in classificatore/main.py I set debug to True

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run( host = '0.0.0.0' , debug = True )
```

I get

```
* Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
2019-05-03 08:40:57,857  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-05-03 08:40:57,858  * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    start_http_server(8000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prometheus_client/exposition.py", line 181, in start_http_server
    httpd = _ThreadingSimpleServer((addr, port), CustomMetricsHandler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/server.py", line 137, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I guess I'm messing around with ports but I'm still a newby in Docker.

Any help will be very welcome!

Thank you in advance

EDIT 1: the output of `$docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                                   NAMES
bb7c9a5b80eb        encoder_mpeg-pre-encoder   "python main.py"         2 minutes ago       Up 12 seconds                                                                       encoder_mpeg-pre-encoder_1
6a523161c191        encoder_classificatore     "python /src/main.py"    2 minutes ago       Exited (1) 11 seconds ago                                                           encoder_classificatore_1
e5d0287e9129        encoder_aggregatore        "python /src/main.py"    5 minutes ago       Up 12 seconds               0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp                                  encoder_aggregatore_1
907327ef0342        grafana/grafana:5.1.0      "/run.sh"                6 minutes ago       Up 18 seconds               0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp                                  encoder_grafana_1
e57064e76aa1        busybox                    "sh"                     6 minutes ago       Exited (0) 18 seconds ago                                                           encoder_files_1
2b42907a31c4        rabbitmq                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Up 18 seconds (healthy)     4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp   encoder_rabbit_1
3f509108b69d        prom/prometheus            "/bin/prometheus --c…"   6 minutes ago       Up 18 seconds               0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp                                  encoder_prometheus_1
```

Comment: There are two services on port 5000 in your container. Please post the full code of `classificatore/main.py`

Comment: @bluesmonk thank you, I've just posted the full code

Comment: using `DEBUG=True` reloads the dev server every time there is a change in `main.py`, running the script. This is true also for the line `start_http_server(8000)`, which fails because there is already an instance listening on that port. You'll need to handle the lifecycle of whatever that is outside of `main.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are changing the file inside docker. In an ideal environment, you need to change it at the host where actual development is happening & then build & run the compose.

Change `classificatore/main.py` file at docker host -

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run( host = '0.0.0.0' , debug = True )
```

Build and run the app again -

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up -d
```

It's best to use environment variables in such cases so that you need not change your source code every time for the debug switch.

To build the compose again from scratch run below commands -

```
$ docker-compose down -v
$ docker-compose build --no-cache
$ docker-compose up -d
```

In case you still receive errors, share the output of `docker ps` after running above commands.

I could see below error -

```
  File "/src/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    start_http_server(8000)
```

Your `docker ps` output shows that something else is already running on port 8000, probably aggegatore. Post that `start_http_server(8000)` is also trying to run on port 8000 on the same network which is causing the conflict here. Try changing the ports in the desired way so that conflict doesn't occur.

Comment: still get the same error. I posted the output you required.

Comment: Updated my answer(last 10 lines). It seems like something else is already running on port 8000.

Comment: yes, there are other processes running on the same port, also aggregatore, as you pointed out. As suggested in the other answer, everytime I reload the classificatore container I get a conflict because the previous instance is still running in port 8000. I'm using Flask since yesterday and Docker since 1 week, I guess it will be an hard job to solve this issue. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 1:

By using `DEBUG=True` you are telling Flask to reload the server each time `main.py` changes. In doing so, it calls `main.py` each time, killing the app and then restarting it in port `5000` in the process. That is expected behaviour.

The problem is that you also have a call to `start_http_server(8000)` that creates a server in port `8000`. Flask does not handle this process, leading to an Exception because the previous instance is already using the port.

The error traceback is clear about this (`OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`), but the hint is that the error happens after *restarting* the server.

```
2019-05-03 08:40:57,857  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-05-03 08:40:57,858  * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    start_http_server(8000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/prometheus_client/exposition.py", line 181, in start_http_server
    httpd = _ThreadingSimpleServer((addr, port), CustomMetricsHandler)
```

You'll need to handle the lifecycle of that service outside of the `main.py` script, or handle the exception.

EDIT 2:

Your problem has nothing to do with docker, and is more about setting up *prometheus* inside a Flask application. Note that  `prometheus_client/exposition.py` is the one that is raising the exception.

There are some extensions that help with this, for instance:

- https://github.com/sbarratt/flask-prometheus or
- https://github.com/hemajv/flask-prometheus

Maybe [this](https://blog.codeship.com/monitoring-your-synchronous-python-web-applications-using-prometheus/) sheds some light on the solution as well, *but please note that this is not what you are asking here*.

EDIT 3:

I suggest first giving these extensions a shot, which means  refactoring your code. From there and if there is a problem implementing the extensions, then create another question providing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your hints, but it is not completely clear what I shall do. I understand I'm calling the devserver each time I reload the container and this causes the error, but is there a simple way to get around this?

Comment: I've pasted some links to flask extensions, but I suggest you create another question.